# Insert json object input field to database

Tags: sql, json, codeigniter

I have a drop down list that display input fields according the select value. Everything works good so far. I want to insert the select and the input fields values in database with codeigniter. The inputs are a result of json object. How can i send the inputs fields value to the controller to save them ?

1- MY VIEW

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/save');?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Seguro médico</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select name="seguro_medico" id="seguro_medico">
                <option></option>
                <?php 
                  foreach($seguro_medico as $row)
                  { 
                    echo '<option   
                    value="'.$row->id_ap.'">'.$row->medical_insurance.'</option>';
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="seguro_input">
        <?php 
          if (isset($GET_INPUT))
          {
          foreach($GET_INPUT as $get_input)
          {
        ?>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>
                  <?=$get_input->name;?>
              </label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" name="<?=$get_input->name;?>">
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php
            }
            }
          ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="send_citas" value="Send">
</form>
```

2- JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#seguro_medico").on('change', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('
            admin / get_input ');?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                seguro_medico: $("#seguro_medico").val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                var inputs = [];

                $.each(data, function(id, value) {
                    inputs.push(
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<label>' + value.name + '</label>' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
                        '<input type="text" name="' + value.name + '">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                });

                $("#seguro_input").html(inputs.join(''));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know how to get the inputs value displayed after a select to the controller.

Comment: Can somebody help me or suggest me something ?